# Can I work collaboratively with GWT plus AngularJs.?

Tags: java, angularjs, gwt

I am trying to collaborate GWT and Angular js. I am working with GWt since past 1 year. GWT itself coverts data to js.
but because of some limitations in gwt, we need to convert our product to work with angular + gwt.
I am new to AngularJs. Can anybody help to figure this out. As per my finding, i get to know that there is a way to work with both is library, but I don't want to use libraries. Any suggestions are invited.

Comment: Take a look at JsInterop.

Comment: I guess its supports only GWT 2.8.0 version. we are using GWT 2.6.0

Comment: Ok, that was not mention inside the question. Then you can try JSNI.